# Array destructuring

Tags: reactjs, setstate, destructuring

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value }); 
};
```

Why need to use array destructuring inside setState?  Since i already use {} destructuring name and value why I cannot just write this.setState({ name: value }) ?

Comment: You're _not_ using destructuring (array or otherwise) in `this.setState({ [name]: value });`. That's just a dynamic object property.

Comment: `name` is a variable, not necessarily the actual name of the object key. They would not be the same.

Comment: This method is a pattern for handling multiple inputs, like `<input name="a" onChange={handleChange} />`, so that you can reuse the same change handler for a variable number of inputs without using inline arrow functions/currying to get the name of the state key to update

Comment: `var key = 'hello'; var obj = { [key]: 'world' }; console.log(obj);` will output `{ hello: "world" }`. See [Object computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) for more info.

Comment: `let x = { name: value}` is equal to: `let x = {}; x["name"] = value`. While `let x = {[name]: value}` is equal to `let x = {}; x[name] = value;` See the difference? While in the first case you literaly have an object with a property `name`, the second case snippet creates an object, where the property's name comes from the content of the `name` variable. That does not anything have to do with array destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, this method is used to handle multiple inputs. Say you have two input elements in your code:

```
<input name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
<input name="password" onChange={handleChange} />
```

When you do

```
this.setState({ [name]: value });
```

you can use a single onChange handler to update the state for both, email as well as password. This would basically translate to:

```
this.setState({ email: 'xyz' });
this.setState({ password: 'abc' });
```

If you use `name` instead of `[name]`, that would basically update the `name` key in the state, not the input field name i.e. `email` & `password` in this case.